# XNA orientation of models

Tags: c#, xna

I cannot get the orientation of models correct. In this project the user loads 3 DXF files.

- DXF 1 is the model represented by 3dfaces.
- DXF 2 is the 3dpoly representing the path of the camera as driving on the left.
- DXF 3 is the 3dpoly providing a path for oncoming traffic.

The first two data sets are dealt with correctly in the C#/XNA development. The user can drive along the road using up and down keyboard keys. But I fail at the third process. I cannot get the orientation of oncoming traffic correct. The position is ok, one van at every 100 metres, but the orientation is wrong.

The strangest of all is the normal method to transform the models to the correct place and orientation is causing the models to be on top of the camera! Where did I go wrong? I have made the source code available at the following URL, so you can view the code and see where I went wrong (the zip includes the DXF files used for testing):

http://www.4shared.com/zip/Lk3xmCtO

Thanks in advance.. Kevin.

This is the most incorrect part:

```
Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(VanPos[vi]);
Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[Van.Bones.Count];
Van.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);
foreach (ModelMesh modmesh in Van.Meshes)
{
foreach (BasicEffect be1 in modmesh.Effects)
{
    be1.World = transforms[modmesh.ParentBone.Index] * worldMatrix;
```

this results in the models being placed at the camera position.
using just the CreateTranslation is placing the models at the correct place but the orientation is incorrect.

Comment: http://dc617.4shared.com/img/ZZaacc6f/s2/0.6480764457213543/opposite.png

Comment: You really should include the relevant parts of your code in the question instead of linking to a zip file. Specifically the part which sets the matrices of the cars

Comment: : (   .. .. sorry about that but I think there is a basic principal in XNA I do not understand. The only way a developer will be able to discover the core problem here will be to look at the entire project. Its still short and easy to look at. The entire development is not yet complete.

Comment: Dervall .. Hi there.. you were the only person to respond to my question on irregular triangles. If you look at this code you will see that the problem has been solved. The TIN is drawn and textured now. I used Reimers custom vertex to solve the problem. Thanks for your help. The development is almost complete now. Just need to solve this orientation problem. The orientation should be set using the vertices provided by the DXF.

Comment: Apparently, I'm the only one to have tried to answer *all* of your questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never setting an orientation, which means that your stuff is never going to rotate. From some code I have laying around, this is how I draw model meshes.

Key points:

- You need to include the projection and view matrix and set them to your effects. You might do this, in some following code.
- An `Orientation` matrix needs to be created. There are lots of convenience functions to help you do this like `Matrix.CreateRotationY`
- Beware of ordering when multiplying matrices. I'm sure you've noticed this but the order really matters. I tend to mess this up and fiddle around with the multiplication order to make things work :)

  ```
  public void Draw(Matrix projection, Matrix view)
  {
      // Copy any parent transforms.
      var transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
      model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

      foreach (var mesh in model.Meshes)
      {
          // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
          // as our camera and projection.
          foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
          {
              Matrix world = Orientation; // <- A Matrix that is the orientation
              world.Translation = Position; // <- A Vector3D representing position
              effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                  world;

              effect.View = view;
              effect.Projection = projection;
          }
          // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
          mesh.Draw();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Okay. I applied this. Recorded orientation on loading DXF path. Use orientation in draw (as provided in answer) .. but all models are placed at the camera position. ???

Comment: And what is the models position? I.e. what are you setting to `world.Translation`?

Comment: yes world.translation with bone transform results in models at camera position! ? but .. translation without bone transform is placing the models at the correct place ... very strange ... I have definitely made a terrible mistake somewhere earlier in the code  : (

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM!!!! The Problem is the FBX .. The Model ... It was created using AutoCAD 2012. I just created a new Model in Blender and ... now translation is working correctly!! This question can be deleted .. SORRY!!!

Comment: @zeppeldep questions aren't deleted unless they contain *serious* problems. Someone might have a similar problem later on and be helped by your question. Glad you found the solution.

Comment: @zeppeldep also, I noticed you tried to edit the answer to add your comment. This is not the way to do it. You want to use the **comment** function to add comments, not editing the answer itself - which is why the edit got rejected.